Difficulty in KiCad laying out a PCB, can't grab small components!
Firstly I don't understand why in KiCad there isn't something that can help in the layout of components that are supposed to be at least proximal, instead it just throws everything into one big pile of stuff and you are supposed to disentangle this all by yourself manually. I mean I have been playing with graph layout algorithms and a simple force-based layout would already help so much to just have at least a somewhat reasonable distribution.
Then it would also help to just say somewhere that I want a ground plane layer and a power distribution layer so that these things could already be squared away without me doing everything manually.
I generally don't understand why people insist on doing it all manually, why are auto-routers so looked down upon? I think auto-layout can help get started. Then I can sill move stuff around.
But even just grabbing a resistor or capacitor or diode in SMD format on this PCB layout window is a nightmare! Please someone tell me how I can safely grab such component and not just one of its pads or markings!

I’m voting to close this question because it's a rant, not a question.

There is a clear question! How to grab small components? And all the rest are also questions.

Not sure why small components are causing you issues (maybe it's something I have to visually see to know what's going on) but regarding your question about why auto-routing is "frowned upon" is because they have no regard to your DRC. It's fine to get you started but if you have DRC in place, prepare yourself for a million violations. Truthfully it might take longer to fix the mistakes of auto-routing than to do routing yourself.

On the bottom right corner of the PCB editor, uncheck text and pads. Then it will grab whole components instead of its parts.

In KiCad PCB Editor 8.0.4 menu, if you turn on View | Appearance Manager, there is a "Selection Filter" with a bunch of checkboxes to filter out what kinds of objects you want to be able to grab (e.g. Footprints, Tracks, Pads, Zones, Dimensions, Text, Vias, etc.).

a: use the mouse wheel to zoom.
b: select a region that contains the component
Auto layout and auto route seem cool, but then I'd need to tell the schematic entry what all the bypass capacitors need to be close to, and which tracks need to be wide or short etc...

Making such annotations to the schematics is exactly what should be done! For example, marking a wire as sustaining a certain current (to already define the width and perhaps thickness), voltage potential (to define the spacing to the next trace), and frequency (to constrain length and bends). This would make total sense and is what intelligent software should be all about. Bypass capacitors too, obviously! For example, proximity in schematics should translate to proximity in the PCB! It's all so obvious that that is what should be done.

@GuntherSchadow Very frequently, it's obvious that something "should" be done, and in no way obvious how it should or even could be done. Autorouters are one of those things; every engineer I've ever worked with who's used one has agreed that they cause more trouble than they're worth, unless you're doing 80s-style PCBs full of logic ICs running at a handful of MHz tops. Anything layout-sensitive (which is most modern electronics) is absolutely butchered by autorouters.

Cross probe them from your schematic. Flip to the schematic editor, select them there, flip over to the PCB editor, move the already selected components.

This is an excellent suggestion! With this I can finally identify functionally related components and move them to a far away space, organize them there, and then move them in place on an actual board. Very, very, extremely useful suggestion!!!!

@GuntherSchadow You are most welcome. That's how I normally work after initial transfer to PCB, select a functional group of components in schematic, move it on the PCB from the initial lined up components and yellow spaghetti mesh, do initial placement and some routing, repeat for all blocks, floorplan blocks together, micromanage placement and do final routing.
